# Flat vector bundles and constant transition functions

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-geometry

Let $E\to M$  be a vector bundle endowed with a flat connection. Then, does $E$ admit a bundle atlas with constant transition functions?

For a vector bundle with constant transition functions, are the possible structure groups in correspondence with representations of the fundamental group of the base?

Thanks.

Comment: isn't this the riemann-hilbert correspondence?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit please?

Comment: Yes indeed.  Choose a cover of your space by (say) contractible open sets, and choose trivializations of your bundle on those sets by flat sections.  Then this choice of trivialization will give locally constant transition functions.

Comment: That's well-known (and, I am afraid, not appropriate for MO). See for instance the first section of Deligne, *Equations différentielles ...*, Springer LN 163.

Comment: That is well-known for you, maybe. Plus, what is wrong about posing a question whose answer is well-known for some users? This way it can be answered properly by precisely those users. Otherwise, what is the point of having a website to pose math questios?

Comment: I guess what prevents the same thing to happen in a non-flat vector bundle is the fact that we cannot always find constant local frames?

Comment: This site is for research level questions. One like yours is for me borderline but you should at least look for references elsewhere. Or try to prove it yourself. Here's the Wikipedia article: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_vector_bundle

Comment: In particular, you've probably learned that a Riemannian metric is flat iff its curvature vanishes. The proof is basically the same.

Comment: I see. However the second question

"For a vector bundle with constant transition functions, are the possible structure groups in correspondence with representations of the fundamental group of the base?"

Remains unanswered. Is this also too basic?

Comment: Well, it is a consequence of the first part. Did you figure it out on your own? Again the proof is similar to an analogous description of flat Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: I know that a Riemannian metric is flat if and only if its curvature vanishes. However I don't see how proving that (which I did) helps finding that the transition functions are representations of the fundamental group of the manifold. Since apparently this is an undergraduate level question, could you please point out a reference?

Comment: S.S., you might find the appendix to my article arXiv:0710.0681 helpful in regards to your second question (to which the answer is "Yes").  It contains a discussion of the standard facts about the holonomy correspondence between (gauge equivalence classes of) flat connections and (conjugacy classes of) representations of the fundamental group.

Comment: There's a proof of the first question in Voisin's Hodge Theory book (Vol. 1, page 229-231).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brief answer to your first question:

Let $(M, \mathscr{O}_M)$ be a real or complex manifold, where $\mathscr{O}_M$ is the structure sheaf. Let $\mathbb{K}$ denoted either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, as appropriate, and $\mathbb{K}_M$ the corresponding constant sheaf on $M$. Let $\nabla: \mathscr{E} \to \Omega^1 \otimes_{\mathscr{O}_M} \mathscr{E}$ be the linear connection, which is a $\mathbb{K}_M$-linear map.

If the connection is flat, then $\mathscr{L} := \ker(\nabla)$ is a local system of $\mathbb{K}_M$-modules (i.e. a locally free sheaf). Pick a trivializing open cover, and then you can see that the corresponding transition functions must be locally constant for $\mathscr{L}$.

Since the vector bundle can be recovered from the local system by tensoring $\mathscr{O}_M\otimes_{\mathbb{K}_M} \mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{E},$ then the vector bundle admits locally constant transition functions as well.