# Flat bundle and constant transition functions

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over connected manifold $M$ and let $\nabla$ be a connection on $E$ i.e. a map $\nabla: \Gamma^{\infty}(M,E) \to \Omega^1(M) \otimes \Gamma^{\infty}(M,E)$. It can be extended to act on whole $\Omega(M,E):=\Omega^{\bullet}(M) \otimes \Gamma^{\infty}(M,E)$. Although $\nabla$ is not $C^{\infty}(M)$ linear its square $\nabla^2$ (understood as a composition of original connection with the extended one: $\nabla \circ \nabla$) is $C^{\infty}(M)$ linear. A bundle $E$ is called *flat* if $\nabla^2=0$. I would like to understand why

> Flatness is equivalent to the condition that the transition functions of $E$ are constant.

I know that this was discussed already, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148154/flat-vector-bundles-and-constant-transition-functions) however the explanation there is rather sketchy and I would like to see some more detailed argument (and also understand the converse implication).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be careful - as written, your claim is not quite correct. The zero-curvature condition $\nabla^2 = 0$ is the definition of flatness of the *connection* $\nabla$. We say the bundle $E$ is flat if it admits *some* flat connection; but there many connections on any bundle, most of which will not be flat.

Similarly, there are many bundle atlases for any given bundle, which will have different collections of transition functions; so the correct claim is the following:

> A bundle admits a flat connection if and only if it admits a bundle atlas in which all the transition functions are constant.

We can think of a bundle atlas as a collection $(U_i, e_{(i)})$ where the $U_i$ are open sets covering $M$ and each $e_{(i)}$ is a frame field for $E|_{U_i}$, i.e. a map $e_{(i)} : U_i \times \mathbb R^k \to E|_{U_i}$ such that for each $p$, $e_{(i)}(p) : v \mapsto e_{(i)}(p,v)$ is a linear isomorphism $\mathbb R^k \to E_p$. The transition functions are  $$\phi_{ij}(p) = e_{(i)}(p)^{-1} \circ e_{(j)}(p) \in GL(k,\mathbb R).$$ The correspondence between flat atlases (those with constant transition functions) and flat connections is simple: the frame fields in the atlas should be parallel. If you're given a flat connection $\nabla$, then you can build a flat atlas like so:

- Choose a good cover $U_i$ of $M$; i.e. so that $U_i$ and $U_i \cap U_j$ are contractible.
- On each $U_i$, choose an arbitrary frame at a single point $x_i \in U_i$, then extend to a frame field $e_{(i)}$ defined over $U_i$ by $\nabla$-parallel transport. (Flatness of $\nabla$ and contractibility of $U_i$ ensure that this gives a well-defined parallel frame.)
- Note that $$\nabla \phi_{ij} = \nabla {e_{(i)}}^{-1} e_{(j)} + {e_{(i)}}^{-1} \nabla e_{(j)} = 0$$ since both $e_{(i)},e_{(j)}$ are parallel; so each $\phi_{ij}$ is constant.

On the other hand, suppose you are given a flat atlas $(U_i,e_{(i)}).$ On each $U_i$ we can define a flat connection $\nabla_{(i)}$ by declaring that $e_{(i)}$ is a parallel frame. The fact that $\phi_{ij}$ is constant is then exactly the condition you need to ensure that $\nabla_{(i)}$ and $\nabla_{(j)}$ agree on $U_i \cap U_j,$ since it tells you that the vectors comprising $e_{(j)}$ can be written as a constant linear combination of those comprising $e_{(i)}$. Thus we get a well-defined global flat connection by gluing all the $\nabla_{(i)}$ together.

Comment: Dear Anthony, could you elaborate on why do we need the contractibility of $U_i$'s in order to get a well-defined parallel frame? @anthony-carapetis

Comment: @Tepes: For the extension by parallel transport to be well-defined, you need parallel transport along any two different paths joining the same points to give the same result. This is true for flat connections when the two paths are homotopic; but for non-homotopic paths you could get different results - this is *holonomy*. Thus you need some topological condition to rule out non-homotopic paths - contractible is sufficient, but just simply connected should be good enough too.