# Representation of fundamental group and flat bundle

Tags: representation-theory, vector-bundles, fundamental-groups, connections

My question is inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636077/flat-bundle-and-constant-transition-functions) discussion where the two notions of flatness for vector bundle are discussed.

> I would like to understand the one-to-one correspondence between flat bundles over a manifold $M$ and representation of fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$.

Comment: Have you googled for this and/or looked in textbooks? This is a subject often discussed in many places!

Comment: The very first result I get is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17786/why-are-local-systems-and-representations-of-the-fundamental-group-equivalent

Comment: You need to understand what is the holonomy of a connexion. Then notice that a flat connexion is precisely when the holonomy is the same along homotopic path, and you are left with a local system. This is very standard then that local systems are in bijection with representations of $\pi_1(M)$.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will take a look at this discussion